# Reledmac : Paragraph Spacing Stanza And Center Environment

Tags: reledmac, parskip, setspace

I'm using `reledmac` for typesetting critical edition and text with commentaries.
I've experienced that customizing paragraph spacing with `parskip` package has no effect.
Using `setspace` package to increase the line separation works, but it doesn't create the effect that paragraph are further away than consecutive lines. I don't use indentation for paragraph, so the more separation is needed for the effect.
Using `\AtEveryPend{\vspace{\parskip}}` helps in getting more space though.

I also realized that since paragraph are define by `\pstart` and `\pend` in numbered section, so using `\par` is useless. Although, I'll like to fully understand scope of \par inside the numbering environment.

For line breaks, we use `\\` command as usual.

Since I use `\autopar`, so a blank line before and after the para generates `\pstart` and `\pend` automatically, and lines are numbered.

In my another project(MWE is not presented here), double blank line is needed to insert \pstart and \pend automatically and If I use a single blank line, it generates linebreak and line numbers go away. I can't understand why this happens? Most probably because of some conflict, but I'll take it later in comments after having some clarity of MWE presented here.

If I try to use \begin{center}...\end{center}, it halts compilation. If I add them between \pstart and \pend, as shown in MWE below, the code compiles. But, the last line is not numbered and it's spacing is also disturbed. I got a blank line numbered too. See image below:[image: centered para not numbered properly]

> I've just figured out after testing that the package setspace is
> conflicting with reledmac and creating a line with no number, and
> making the gap shrink before and after an environment. I'll like to
> know a way to customize line spacing and paragraph spacing inside
> reledmac, without using setspace package.

> More experience here, the package perpage also has conflict with reledmac.

> I definitely need a list of all packages conflicting with reledmac, to avoid using them.

I tried to use \stanza, as shown in MWE, but it fails to compile. It throws 'missing number treated as zero.

So, basically I want to understand how paragraph works in reledmac's numbering environment and how I can customize it to get continuous line numbers while changing environments(like center, quote, quoting) inside it.

Any help provided is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,p]{libertinus}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english, main=latin]{babel}
\babeltags{english = english}

\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D},noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xarrangement[C]{threecol}
\Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
\AtEveryPend{\vspace{\parskip}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%\usepackage[skip=30pt]{parskip}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{english}
        \date{}
        \title{Critical notes}
        %\maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            This file provides examples of critical notes with reledmac.
            A critical note is associated to a lemma, marked by \verb+\edtext+, and referenced by the line numbers of the lemma.
            If a critical notes refers to a long lemma, we can use \verb+lemma+ to obtain an abbreviated form.
            
            Here we use four series of critical notes.
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Each note of series A has its own paragraph.
                \item Each note of series B has its own paragraph, but there are arranged in two columns.
                \item Each note of series C has its own paragraph, but there are arranged in three columns.
                \item The notes of series D are arranged in the same paragraph.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{abstract}
    \end{english}
    
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar
    
    \edtext{Lorem}{
        \Afootnote{A critical note}
        \Bfootnote{Critical note in series B}
        \Cfootnote{Critical note in series C}
        \Dfootnote{loram}}
    \edtext{ipsum}{
        \Afootnote{An other critical note}
        \Bfootnote{Other critical note in series B}
        \Cfootnote{Other critical note in series C}
        \Dfootnote{ipsam}}
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \edtext{Fusce sed dolor libero. Aenean rutrum vestibulum lacus ut pretium. Fusce et auctor lectus. Ut et commodo quam, quis gravida orci. Nullam at risus elementum, suscipit enim a, pellentesque mi}
    {\lemma{Fusce\ldots mi}
        \Afootnote{A long critical note}
        \Bfootnote{Again B}
        \Cfootnote{Again C}
        \Dfootnote{omit}}.
    Morbi commodo, ligula vel consectetur accumsan, \\massa metus egestas velit, eu fringilla leo ante in turpis. Vivamus ut tellus sollicitudin, facilisis ipsum sit amet, \\tincidunt odio. Maecenas tincidunt dolor sed ante blandit tincidunt. Etiam vulputate ultricies facilisis.राम\\
    Morbi commodo, ligula vel consectetur accumsan, massa metus egestas velit, eu fringilla leo ante in turpis. Vivamus ut tellus sollicitudin, facilisis ipsum sit amet, tincidunt odio. Maecenas tincidunt dolor sed ante blandit tincidunt. Etiam vulputate ultricies facilisis.
    
        \pstart\begin{center}
        Morbi commodo,\\
        ligula vel consectetur\\
        accumsan,
    \end{center}
    \pend
    
     massa metus egestas velit, eu 
     \stanza
     fringilla leo&
     ante in turpis.&
     Vivamus ut tellus sollicitudin,\&
     facilisis ipsum sit amet, tincidunt odio. Maecenas tincidunt dolor sed ante blandit tincidunt. Etiam vulputate ultricies facilisis.
    
    \endnumbering
    Morbi commodo, ligula vel consectetur accumsan, massa metus egestas velit, eu fringilla leo ante in turpis. Vivamus ut tellus sollicitudin, facilisis ipsum sit amet, tincidunt odio. Maecenas tincidunt dolor sed ante blandit tincidunt. Etiam vulputate ultricies facilisis.
    Morbi commodo, ligula vel consectetur accumsan, massa metus egestas velit, eu fringilla leo ante in turpis. Vivamus ut tellus sollicitudin, facilisis ipsum sit amet, tincidunt odio. Maecenas tincidunt dolor sed ante blandit tincidunt. Etiam vulputate ultricies facilisis.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Basically, reledmac split line between \pstart...\pend, number them and deal with footnote insertion, then typetseet them. 

The problem you have, which is explicitly mentionned in the handbook,l is that any macro which insert vertical skip, (like the \begin{center} and \end{center} macro) disturb the way reledmac split the line. So you CANT't use them inside a \pstart...\pend structure.

Comment: so : instead of manuel line break, use stanza (that for it, but don't forget to define stanza indent), and for centring, call center environment inside optional argument of \stanza and endstanza.

Comment: And pergage work perfectly with reledmac... so .... I don't know what said to to you.

Comment: @Maïeul, Thanks for you replies.
I now understand that I can't use other environments inside numbered env. You have suggested a way to get similar results with stanza, I'll try to implement the same.

I'll still like to customize para separation and line separation. I can't use setspace for that. So, please suggest a solution which doesn't conflict with line numbers.

If I use perpage, single blank line was generating linebreak, instead of \pend\pstart. So, I reported that.
I'll check and report again.

Comment: I've implemented the centered verse solution.
It appears that I can not insert critical notes inside the \stanza \& if the note contains \stanza \&.
Please, confirm if it is correct.
If yes, please suggest a solution.

Comment: well, of course, you cant have a \stanza inside a not, stanza is a global markup..

for space between paragraph, just \vspace inside optional argument of \pend...

Comment: you should look on the handbook and auxiliiry examples.

Also, in your initial message, you have many question, which is not  very useful to help you...

Comment: I understand that \stanza is not very useful in my case. I may have to create a new \pstart manually with \centering for compatibility with verses in critical notes.
I hope this is possible somehow.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to use \pstart with \vspace. Since, I'm using \autopar, I think I've to use \AtEveryPstart. Am I correct?

Comment: I didn't understood that you need verse in footnote, sorry.

Yes, you can also use \AtEveryPstart. But not that using \autopar is not incompatible to use ponctually explicit pstart.

Comment: Thanks @Maïeul. I'll be creating separate questions for each of the problems. I hope to get clarification/solution from you there.